# Sed: How to replace a string which includes multiple special characters?

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to comment a line in `/etc/sudoers` through a shell script.
That's the relevant line I'd like to edit:

```
# grep '\!requiretty' /etc/sudoers
Defaults:nagios !requiretty
```

But it seems like the pattern I'm using with `sed` is incorrect, my tries:

```
# sed -i 's/^Defaults\:nagios$/#Defaults:nagios !requiretty/g' /etc/sudoers
# sed -i 's/^Defaults:nagios$/#Defaults:nagios !requiretty/g' /etc/sudoers
# sed -i 's/^Defaults:nagios$/#Defaults:nagios !requiretty/g' /etc/sudoers
# sed -i 's/^Defaults:nagios$/\#Defaults:nagios !requiretty/g' /etc/sudoers
# sed -i 's/^Defaults:nagios$/\#Defaults:nagios \!requiretty/g' /etc/sudoers
# sed -i 's/^Defaults:nagios$/^#Defaults:nagios !requiretty/g' /etc/sudoers
# sed -i 's/^Defaults\:nagios$/^#Defaults:nagios !requiretty/g' /etc/sudoers
# sed -i 's/^Defaults\:nagios$/#Defaults:nagios \!requiretty/g' /etc/sudoers
```

None of the above worked...

Can someone please assist me with the correct regex?

Thanks in advance

Comment: From your description it's not clear to me what the line looks like before and what it shall be after edit. It's also important to know what other lines look like. If there is no similar file the regex can be much simpler … A tip: when developing a regex start with the simplest part and add details step by step. This way you'll know which part works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well ... `sudoers` is not meant to be writable by anyone -- even root.  You're supposed to edit it with the `visudo` command instead for security reasons.

I think you might have it backwards though since the first part of the `sed` substitution is the *find*.  The second part is the replacement.  So you would want to do something like:

```
sed -i 's/^Defaults:nagios !requiretty$/#Defaults:nagios/'
```

This will also remove the `requiretty`.  If all you want is to add the `#` you could just do:

```
sed -i 's/^Defaults:nagios !requiretty$/#&/'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, your second command is the one I was looking for.
Does the `&` stand for the `find` pattern of the sed?

Comment: @ItaiGanot pretty much -- it is the zeroth match or whatever was matched by the pattern.  You could also use `\1` etc. for other capture groups but you are not doing any capturing with this pattern.